# Not able to get error code and description in Dtexec /ISServer command in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server, logging, dtexec, ssis-2019

I'm running a SSIS package which is developed in Visual Studio 2019 using dtexec command given below. We are using SQL Server Management Studio 2019 version. Packages are deployed to Integration Services Catalogs.

```
DTEXEC /ISSERVER "\SSISDB\Folder\Project\Package.dtsx" /SERVER xxx /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING EW
```

If there is an error in the package, all I see is this:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 15.0.2000.5 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  1:56:31 PM
Package execution on IS Server failed. Execution ID: 457, Execution Status:4.
To view the details for the execution, right-click on the Integration Services Catalog, and open the [All Executions] report
Started:  1:56:31 PM
Finished: 1:56:45 PM
Elapsed:  13.703 seconds
```

To check the error, I should go to `All Executions` on Integration Services Catalog.

If I run the Dtexec command from skybot job, how do I get the error log if skybot job fails? Ideally, I'd like to get error, error code, source and description details in the following format:

```
Started:  9:00:12 PM
Error: 2021-01-11 21:00:13.15
   Code: 0x00000008
   Source: SQL_Task 
   Description: The script returned a failure result.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  9:00:12 PM
Finished: 9:00:13 PM
Elapsed:  0.733 seconds
```